# Items from Ngselect are undefined, what did i miss?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a ngselect which displays with a dropdownmenu all my heroes and villains :

```
<ng-select class="herodrop" [items]="heroes"
              placeholder="Wähle aus" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="chosenHero"></ng-select>

<ng-select class="villaindrop" [items]="villains"
               placeholder="Wähle aus" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="chosenVillain"></ng-select>
```

Then in another block, i want the chosenHero and chosenVillain to fight each other, i call them here:

```
<button class="ggV" (click)="vsVillain(chosenVillain, chosenHero)">Hit a Villain!</button>
    <button class="ggH" (click)="vsHero(chosenVillain, chosenHero)">Hit a Hero!</button>
```

These two methods can be found in my fight.component.ts
They save the heros/villains HP in num and creates a random number from 1-100 and subtracts the original hp from the created random number, so its kind of a random attack:

```
vsVillain(x: Villain, y: Hero ): void {
    const num: number = x.hp;
    const zufall: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    console.log(y.name + ' hat dem Schurken ' + (num - zufall)  + ' HP abgezogen!');

}

  vsHero(x: Villain, y: Hero ): void {
    const num: number = y.hp;
    const zufall: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    console.log(x.name + ' hat dem Helden ' + (num - zufall)  + ' HP abgezogen!');

  }
```

but when i run it on my website, my console.log tells me my two objects are undefined and NaN.
what did i miss?

EDIT:

```
export class FightComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[] = [];
  villains: Villain[] = [];
  heroItems = [];
  villainItems = [];
  chosenHero: Hero;
  chosenVillain: Villain;
  vorherigeHp: number;
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService, private villainService: SchurkeService) { }



ngOnInit(): void {
    this.villainService.getSchurken().subscribe(villainItems => this.villains = villainItems);
    this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroItems => this.heroes = heroItems);
  }
```

Comment: The four variables heroes,villains,chosenHero,chosenVillain defined?

Comment: you must be right my heroItems and villainItems are unused fields, but look in the edit, i used them in the getmethod

Comment: are you using ng2-select?

Comment: it says ng-select, so i guess no